# Can two R packages be on each others depends list?

Tags: r, workflow

Let's say I have 3 packages `A`, `B`, and `C`.

`B` connects to `data repository 1` and has functions specific to that API.

`C` connects to `data repository 2` and has functions specific to that API.

Eventually there will be several more child packages.

Package `A` will have `generic` methods and other common functions (e.g. authentication) that apply to data acquired through `B` and `C`. The rationale here is that this would be a more streamlined way to keep up with development (e.g. one would have to update a single `auth` function rather than doing that inside each child package).  So it makes sense for `A` to be on the depends list for `B` and `C`

But I would also like users to just install `A` and have access to all child packages. For this, I want `B` and `C` to be on its depends list.

Is this possible? Should I have a better workflow?

Comment: Yes. That's what "depends" field is there for in the DESCRIPTION file. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file

Comment: The proper way is to use `Suggests: B C` in `A` and `Depends: A` in both `A` and `B` since `A` doesn't require the others but they do require `A`.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek Thank you. That is helpful. To clarify, since A handles all common functions, it would great if users just had A and used `get_data(data_source="B")` or `get_data(data_source=all)`. We could do away with child packages but right now it is necessary for async development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gregmisc` package is one example like this that installs more focused sub-packages through depends. It doesn't have any functionality, itself, but it certainly could.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gregmisc

Comment: Thanks, the perfect example I was looking for (I use those packages all the time but didn't notice the set up).

Comment: AFAIK the `gregmisc` example is not relevant to the question above, because the subpackages don't depend on `gregmisc`.

Comment: Good point. But I do appreciate it because it does give me a precedent for how this workflow might progress. That is, Package A can be equivalent to the original `gregmisc`, then split up in the future if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Updated in 2021: this is not possible anymore. R RMD Check will complain and return an error - packages cannot depend on each other.

The `gregmisc` package mentioned in a previous answer was removed from CRAN (probably because of this reason).

Comment: Thanks for that, i thought i was going crazy! Do you by any chance have a link to where this change was announced/described?

Comment: No, I'm not sure when this was introduced. Looked up the NEWS file, couldn't find it there neither...